# track visitors data on a website ruby rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to track the information of a user , which pages the user visited, which ip from to a website using ruby on rails, how should I start with ? good sources to study for web visitor tracking program  I m a newbie to ruby/rails

Comment: Take a look at [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want more in-depth analysis than google analytics then Kiss Metrics may be what you are looking for. You can use it to track arbitrary actions or events that occur within your application.

https://www.kissmetrics.com/

**Note:** I do not work for kiss metrics... just a fan.